# Jackson Serialization to return date with timezone

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I had asked a similar question , but asking it here since it is slightly different. I use the below code for serializing the response that get from an external service an return a json response back as part of my service. However when the external service return a time value along with timezone (10:30:00.000-05.00) , jackson is converting it to 15:30:00. How can I return the same value with timezone instead of converting the date?

```
public interface DateFormatMixin {

    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="HH:mm:ss")
    public XMLGregorianCalendar getStartTime();
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="HH:mm:ss")
    public XMLGregorianCalendar getEndTime();
}


public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper responseMapper = new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper();
    responseMapper.addMixIn(Time.class, DateFormatMixin.class);
    return responseMapper;
}
```

Comment: What are you asking? 1. You can just change date format. 2. If you absolutely need to save in specified format, you need TZ coming from external configurations

Comment: I have TZ coming from external service that I consume. It is similar to 10:30:00.000-05.00.  I need to send it in the same format. If I add Z to the pattern specified above , Jackson seems to convert it to UTC and make it -00.00. However I would like to retain the same time and timezone value.

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda/issues/43 and mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE);

Comment: I was able to get the desired format by using datetime format as you mentioned ( @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX",timezone="EST")). However I would have to change the timezone value  to something else if the service that I consume changes the timezone value. I tried to use the new feature in the lnk that you had provided , but that doesn't seem to preserve the timezone.